# How to copy one text file to another text file with changes (editing df files)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am fairly new to progress 4gl. I am trying to copy the contents of one df file into another file where I want to copy everything except the areas of the df file. this is what I have so far.

```
define stream mystream.
input from "C:\OpenEdge\WRK\df file\sample.df".
do while true on endkey undo, leave:
output to "C:\OpenEdge\WRK\df file\test1.df".
end.
output close.
display "finished".
```

I would first like to copy all the contents of the first df file into another df file, but right now I'm getting a blank file. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: The first thing that you are doing wrong is that you are (re)opening output with every iteration of the loop.  Even if it works (it won't because you will get an error about the output target already having a conflicting use...) that will result in the file starting over with every iteration.  You're also not actually doing anything to read the data or write it back out again.  For reading the data you need the IMPORT statement (shown below).  For writing the data you need something like PUT (or MESSAGE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
grep -v AREA < dbname.df > dbname.df2
```

If you are stuck with on OS that lacks "grep" or if you just have an urge  to do it with 4gl code I'd do something like:

```
define variable lineIn as character no-undo.

input from "dbname.df".
output to "dbname.df2".

repeat:

  import unformatted lineIn.                    /* read the data a whole line at a time */

  if lineIn begins "  AREA" then next.          /* skip lines that start with "  AREA" */

  put unformatted lineIn skip.                  /* spit the input line back out */
  if lineIn = "" then put unformatted skip(1).  /* yes, this is a weird thing */

end.
```

Comment: thank you, I have made the changes accordingly so that output statement  is before the iteration. And you logic is working perfectly. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

To copy all the contents of first df file to another df file, use this code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE TEXT-STRING AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(76)".

INPUT FROM "C:\OPENEDGE\WRK\CMD-LOG.DF".

OUTPUT TO "C:\OPENEDGE\WRK\MY.DF".
DO WHILE TRUE ON ENDKEY UNDO, LEAVE:
   IMPORT UNFORMATTED TEXT-STRING.
   MESSAGE TEXT-STRING .
END.

INPUT CLOSE.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```